# Realm App Architecture with Full Sync - how to sync in multi-realm architecture

Tags: realm

Following App Architecture [Guidelines](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/designing-an-architecture-with-multiple-realms), I'd like to keep some of the common data in sync within my on-demand realm.

As a simple example:

1. Cars sync for all clients and are stored in `/commonRealm`
2. Trips only sync for the relevant user and are stored in `/~/driverRealm`

Below is a minimal schema for the app

```
const CarSchema = {
    name: 'Car',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: {type: 'string'},
        make: {type: 'string'},
        model: {type: 'string'}
    }
};

const TripSchema = {
    name: 'Trip',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: {type: 'string'},
        name: {type: 'string'},
        car: {type: 'Car'}
    }
};
```

commonRealm includes the CarSchema only. 
driverReam includes the CarSchema and TripSchema. Cars are never updated by the driver and purpose is really for lookup.

I cannot find an example of how to keep Cars in sync between the realms so that any updates in commonRealm are propagated to the driver's driverRealm.

Listening to the commonRealm Cars object with a subscribe() doesn't help as you cannot get access to data that has been deleted etc.

From what I can deduce from the docs, the architecture for this should actually be something like:

```
const CarSchema = {
    name: 'Car',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: {type: 'string'},
        make: {type: 'string'},
        model: {type: 'string'}
    }
};

const TripSchema = {
    name: 'Trip',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: {type: 'string'},
        name: {type: 'string'},
        carId: {type: 'string'} // foreign key
    }
};
```

commonRealm would include the CarSchema and driverReam would **only include the TripSchema** with carId as a type string for the Car.id - not a *type* of Car. It would be up to the client to run a map/loop to manually join to Car from the commonRealm like:

```
        let tripsWithCar = [];
        trips.forEach(trip => {
            trip.car = commonRealm.objects('Car').filtered(`id == "${trip.carId}"`)[0];
            tripsWithCar.push(trip);
        });
```

I Would like to get some feedback from developers with more experience if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Two questions: why do the models have a var properties that then contain properties? Can't you have those properties at the same level? Why this amount of 'division' and multiple realms? Not saying it's bad, but trying to keep to related realmd sync'd is a lot of extra work (and code) - since CarSchema is common, why don't you just have one realm that contains the car data (as objects) and driver data (as objects)?

Comment: Hi @Jay You wouldn't want all the driver data being replicated to other drivers - for scale and security reasons. Common data should be a Full Sync realm replicated to all drivers so they all have car models. Drivers should have their own secure realm with their trips that are replicated to their devices. Problem is that you cannot query across realms so it seems you need to do joins manually at the client like scenario above.

Comment: Not sure what that means as each object stored in Realm is an independent object. So say you had a Drivers table stored in your Realm; each drivers data is separate from other drivers and you could store millions of drivers. Just like if you had Car data stored in a Cars table. Each car is separate from other cars and all of that data is separate from the drivers. That schema enables you to relate objects. For example, query all drivers that have a certain car, or all drivers that have taken a trip to Napa, or any drivers that are on a trip to Napa in a Lamborghini.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the reply. Perhaps I am missing something if you saying "not sure what that means". My, limited understanding of your suggestion assumes you are not doing Full Sync replication for the realms, but doing Query Based Sync with everything in a single Realm? The docs continuously say not to use Query Based Sync in production and just had that confirmed response from Realm. The architecture suggestion is to split the realms into common and on-demand realms as per: https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/designing-an-architecture-with-multiple-realms.

Comment: Query based sync has shown to be unstable which (IMO) is a good reason not use it. If you read into the Full Sync Query docs, one reason for multiple realms is to respect quantity of data moved and device storage. Since Full stores all data both on the device as well as in Realm Cloud, it could be a lot of data. But here's the important thing, part of that decision is *And which models truly need to be connected via hard links* e.g. a relationship or list. It appears from your use case there is a need to have drivers, trips and the cars related along those lines.

Comment: More importantly is how the data is used - read through the Full example and you'll find that if data is isolated, then you can lean toward separate realms. However if the data works together, if you separate them into different realms, it requires a lot more code. So in their example, you can get a list of user id's on a team. Well, that's not going to do you a lot of good if you want the users names! So then you have to connect to a different realm, run another query to get the names. Whereas, if the Teams and Users are on the same realm, one query does it all.

Comment: OK, seems we on the same page. I don't want driver data synced amongst drivers so needs its own realm - foremost for security and fact that you could have millions of drivers. It seems the DriverSchema in driverReam would need to only store a string id that references a Car and the code on the client would need to manually join across realms as required.

Comment: This may become an issue; *manually join across realms*. While the guide makes it sound like simple lightweight process, it's not. If you keep reading there is almost zero code that deals with moving between realms properly. You can't just connect to another realm and have it work - all of the objects from the first realm must be released first - you cannot maintain a Results from two separate realms. In other words, if you are observing results in a realm and you need to get data from another realm, you must stop observing, get data from second realm, then reconnect and observe the first.